# Object from api request prints in ForEach, but not in List

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm trying to create a List of objects that I received from an API request.  The object is Identifiable.  The strange thing is, when I iterate over the titles parameter of the object in a ForEach loop, it prints out the expected results.  However, when I change it to a List, it doesn't display anything, and it also doesn't give an error or any other indication something went wrong.  What am I missing?

Here is my object:

```
struct Item: Identifiable, Decodable {
    let id = UUID()
    let title: String?
    let canonicalURL: String?
    let unread: Bool?
    let author: String?

    init(title: String?, canonicalURL: String?, unread: Bool?, author: String?){
        self.title = title
        self.canonicalURL = canonicalURL
        self.unread = true
        self.author = author
    }
}
```

and here is my view:

```
@ObservedObject var articlesVM = ArticlesViewModel()

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            ScrollView{

                ForEach (articlesVM.entries) { entry in
                    Text(entry.title!)
                } //THIS WORKS

                List (articlesVM.entries) { entry in
                    Text(entry.title!)
                } //THIS DOESNT WORK

            }.navigationBarTitle("Articles")
            .navigationBarItems(trailing: Button(action: {
                print("Fetching Data")
                self.articlesVM.fetchArticles()
            }, label: {
                Text("Fetch Articles")
            }))
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

List is itself scrollable. Try the following body:

```
var body: some View {
    NavigationView{
        List (articlesVM.entries) { entry in
                Text(entry.title!)
        }.navigationBarTitle("Articles")
        .navigationBarItems(trailing: Button(action: {
            print("Fetching Data")
            self.articlesVM.fetchArticles()
        }, label: {
            Text("Fetch Articles")
        }))
    }
}
```